# Let image take only the remaining space

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want an image to take the remaining space in a `StackLayout`, however somehow this seems to be impossible in XAML. The image always tries to display itself with the maximum size available.

```
<StackLayout>
  <Image Source="{Binding ProfileImage}" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" x:Name="_ButtonShare" Text="Share" />
    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" x:Name="_ButtonExternalLinks" Text="External links"/>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I tried the different Vertical- and HorizontalOptions to achieve this, but the second button is always pushed out of the view. Using a specific height is also not the best solution.

It seems to be possible with a relative layout, however this means that I'm bound to relative values which is not a good idea if I target different devices (like iPhone4S and iPhone5).

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <Image Source="{Binding ProfileImage}" Aspect="AspectFit"
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.7}"/>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.8}"
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.2}">
    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" x:Name="_ButtonShare" Text="Share" />
    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" x:Name="_ButtonExternalLinks" Text="External links"/>
  </StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: a grid will do it. the problem is the stacklayout has no width to fit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a Grid.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Source="{Binding ProfileImage}" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" x:Name="_ButtonShare" Text="Share" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" x:Name="_ButtonExternalLinks" Text="External links"/>
    </Grid>
```